# Relationship between latency and sampling rate of a digital PID controller

Tags: feedback, pid-controller, digital-filter

I am trying to set up a fast digital PID controller. The error signal is read by an ADC and sent to an FPGA. The FPGA uses a PID equation to compute the integer sent to the DAC.

At the moment I am trying to sort out what the sampling rate of my parts needs to be. My naive reasoning is that the total delay of the circuit sets the closed loop bandwidth, and the sampling rate should not be slower than twice that bandwidth (otherwise it will be a limitation). Similarly, the sampling rate need not be orders of magnitude larger than twice the closed loop bandwidth (because that's overkill).

What I would like to know is the following:

1. How are total circuit delay and closed-loop bandwidth related mathematically?
2. Is my reasoning about the sampling rate and bandwidth (from above) correct, or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use the formula :
Delay_margin=
phase_margin/ closed_Bandwith
And
0.2<sampling_period .closed_Bandwith<0.6
See my paper
A PID controller based on the processor utilization artifact within a real-time multitask control system

Answer (score 0):

The sampling rate needs to be more than twice the maximum bandwidth of the signal you wish to process. This is to avoid a phenomena called [Aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Bandlimited_functions).

[image]

In the above diagram you can see the problem; a single set of samples (dots) taken from the red waveform can be mistaken for the blue waveform.

> *the sampling rate should not be chosen to be much larger than the
> closed loop bandwidth because that's overkill.*

Because you need to use an [anti-alias filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-aliasing_filter) between your real world signal and the ADC, you should try and sample a lot higher than twice the signal bandwidth so that the filter doesn't attenuate any in-band wanted signals and the filter has enough spectral area to attenuate higher-than-wanted frequencies to a reasonable low level.

Comment: The ADC input processing may be executed at higher sampling rate than the control loop. The Shannon theorem is still valid for the control loop, the control loop has to be executed \$T_s<\dfrac{\pi}{\omega_{max}}\$

Comment: @Andy aka: Thanks for your answer. I clearly was not specific enough when I said "much larger than". I have made that part more precise thanks to your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

A Sample & Hold is best modelled as a Frequency Mixer with the sum and difference frequencies of both inputs.   But in order to block the sum f's, there must be a wide deadband in between the sum and difference so that the filter phase shift which starts a decade before the attenuation does not reduce the small phase margin between a stable system and one that can be unstable and oscillate.

This "deadband" as I call it, is the difference the Nyquist frequency or 2x your unity-gain bandwidth and the sampling rate ripple that must be attenuated below your SNR spec.

For audio systems, the phase shift in the HF range is unimportant, yet in a closed loop servo , it is critical as the D part of your PID loops advances the phase in the HF band in order to reduce overshoot by "anticipation" or partial gain differentiation of your sensor signal.

How to grasp the tradeoffs?

- oversampling rate vs degradation of Servo Overshoot, Settling time and Jitter
- There are complex methods for each plant type of which there are many, so start with Specs then simulate after research for your desired overshoot, settling time and phase margin.

---

The minimum sampling rate is not only a function of the Dead Time, Ti and the bandwidth for Nyquist Criteria to achieve anti-aliasing but many other factors depending on your type of system and performance required.  These include overshot, settling time, non-linearity, SNR of the output for various disturbances.

Sampling introduces not only latency but an amplitude error just before the next sample and thus a phase delay.  Low Pass Filtering the noise above the Nyquist frequency is a noise disturbance that is amplified by the Kd gain of the system, with it's inherent 90 deg phase lead anticipation advantage, but then nullified when the LPF adds phase lag with increasing rate according to the filter order and attenuation slope below Ts/2. This then reduces the phase margin and increases the overshoot.

It becomes a more complex solution but you must determine the sensitivity to each variable as adding noise tends to reduce Kp the signal gain and aggressive filters to prevent aliasing destroy the derivative gain used to reduce overshoot and maintain stability due to quantization step errors.

For this reason, it is common to see the sampling rate >=10x the f(max) rather than 2.5 to 3x for high SNR signals relative to control systems,  (not audio HiFi). Shannon's Law implies the oversampling rate for the desired SNR
as much as the BER ratio as a function of SNR.

So sample rate cannot be simply defined from latency.

You must define the type of system, any nonlinearities and then the acceptable results for all inputs and disturbances before the optimum sampling method can be determined.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am probably using the word "latency" incorrectly. I edited my question to remove this. Essentially what I meant is that there's a total overall delay of the circuit, from when an analog signal enters the ADC to when the DAC outputs something. Based on some papers I've read about similar systems to the one I am designing, the closed loop bandwidth is limited by this delay. So I would like to know how this total delay and the closed-loop bandwidth are mathematically related.

Comment: Sample delay and group delay are somewhat similar where the latter is the derivative of phase shift t.gd =d.phi/dt  but it is not the sampling that causes problems but the filter phase shift from image rejection or summation frequency noise so over sampling by 10x may give better stability so that Kd is not suppressed by filter and made unstable